# Can't find location provider in Android

Tags: android, android-location

I am new to Android programming and was referring a Programmers' guide to know more about how to use the GPS functionality of a phone. According to the guide-

> Because you are working on a software-based emulator, and not on a real device, the
>   presence of GPS hardware has to be simulated. In this case, Android provides a file in
>   the adb server that simulates having GPS hardware. The file is located at
>   data/misc/location/provider_name, where provider_name represents the location information provider. The provider that Android supplies to you is data/misc/location/gps

To check this, I ran the adb shell, and navigated to the data/misc directory. But there is no **location** directory inside that.

And when I try to use **LocationManager** in my program with either LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER or LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, I get the exception that  Provider "gps"/"network" unknown.

Is this related to there being no location directory in the data/misc? If yes, then how can I get a location provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Eclipse open DDMS , in that u will find Emulator control, there u will find Lang and Lat u can change that values.

and You can find location using location manager class and change the value of lat and lag in ddms..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create it. Refer to the following article for the details: [Providing Mock Location Data](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html#MockData)

Answer (score 0):

In your Eclipse open DDMS , in that u will find Emulator control, there u will find Lang and Lat u can change that values.....
Your Emulator should be in launched state to Edit the corresponding Device Properties

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse go to:

- DDMS->Window->Show View->Emulator Control
- there you will find Latitude & Longitude labels
- set the values to these labels
- send